# iOS Setting Movement Tolerance for Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to ensure that any tap that includes more than some amount of movement is discarded? As it is, what counts as a tap can involve a lot of sliding of the finger. I would like to process a "tap and move" differently by using touchesBegan:, touchesMoved:, etc..

Comment: `UITapGestureRecognizer` has this built in, what is failing?

Comment: Are you saying that `UITapGestureRecognizer` allows you to set tolerances for what counts as a tap?

Comment: It has a tolerance built in as far as I remember. Both for length of press and distance moved. Off the top of my head I can't remember what it is but I'll maybe experiment to see if I can work it out.

Comment: If you want a tap and move then use pan gesture recognizer. You are told when it begins, when it moves and when it ends. All through the state of the recognizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the answer you are looking for.  But I've worked around this by instead doing it myself in the regular touches sequence. For this to work, you would also want to have self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO

```
@interface myView(){
    CGPoint _touchStartPoint;
}
@end

@implementation myView

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    _touchStartPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self checkDistance: [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]];
}


-(void)checkDistance:(CGPoint)p{

    static CGFloat dX;
    dX = p.x - _touchStartPoint.x;

    static CGFloat dY;
    dY = p.y - _touchStartPoint.y;

    static CGFloat dist;
    dist = sqrt(dX*dX + dY*dY);

    /* movement of less than 10 pixels */
    if(dist < 10){
        [self tap];
    }
}

-(void)tap{
    /* do something with your tap*/
}


@end
```

Comment: Even better would be to build this functionality into a custom gesture recognizer.   see WWDC 2012: Building Advanced Gesture Recognizers.